# Meaning of 共催収入

Tags: translation

I have looked in a [good](http://www.linguee.com/english-japanese/search?source=auto&query=%22%E5%85%B1%E5%82%AC%E5%8F%8E%E5%85%A5%22) [many](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%85%B1%E5%82%AC%E5%8F%8E%E5%85%A5) [sources](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%85%B1%E5%82%AC%E5%8F%8E%E5%85%A5) for this expression, and I am at a loss.

It is in the context of an Income and Expenditure Statement (収支報告書) I am translating, and is found adjacent to 寄付金 and ランチョン:

> 共催収入　寄付金
>
> 共催収入　ランチョン

The closest I can get is "joint sponsorship income."

How would you translate 共催収入?

Answer (score 1):

I have discussed this with my superior and it seems that these were in relation to a co-sponsored event. The event was primarily sponsored by the university at which I work, and these two instances were co-sponsored  with a private company.

I have therefore translated them as:

共催収入　寄付金 → Donation received from co-sponsor

共催収入　ランチョン → Donation received from co-sponsor of luncheon

Answer (score 1):

This is Japanese native.
I think ”共催”means co-sponsored for events such as exhibition or concert.
So how about this translation 共済＝co-sponsored fee?